# If using Xcode to make an iOS calculator, how would I add a decimal button?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, calculator

How to add a decimal button so I don't have to do whole numbers? If i wanted any decimal number like 1.2 or 100.4 or 3.0 or anything like that, how would I add it to the calculator I'm making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not giving me much information in your question. How do the other buttons work?

If I was making a calculator I would have a label at the top showing the current reading. On press of a number button I would update the label with the number at the end.

For a decimal button you just add a . to the end of the label. You might want to have a global variable `BOOL hasDecimalPlace` and set it to true so you know if there is already a decimal place. Just remember to set it to false again when you clear the view or do a calculation or similar.

Comment: +1 Is there still a point of confusion for you?  If so, please update your question.  This is a pretty good answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)Decimal:(id)sender{
    NSString *currentText = Text.text;
    if ([currentText rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch].length == 0) {
        Text.text = [Text.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];  
    }
}
```