# Tutorial for iPhone calculator with decimal point

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, calculator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the number of decimal places iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531095/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-decimal-places-ios)
>   [If using Xcode to make an iOS calculator, how would I add a decimal button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531858/if-using-xcode-to-make-an-ios-calculator-how-would-i-add-a-decimal-button)

I am looking for an iOS tutorial on how to make a (simple) iPhone calculator that can do at least the following:add, subtract, multiply, divide, and lets the user input decimal points. I have not been able to find a tutorial like this, so if anyone knows of one, please let me know. I actually did find one where you can add, subtract, multiply, divide, but not do decimal points. If you can tell me how to let the user input a decimal point, there is no need for a further tutorial. The code i am using right now is below.

in the header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CalculatorViewController : UIViewController {

float result;
IBOutlet UILabel *calculatorScreen;
int currentOperation;
float currentNumber;

}


-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)buttonOperationPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)cancelInput;
-(IBAction)cancelOperation;
```

in the main file:

```
#import "CalculatorViewController.h"

@implementation CalculatorViewController


-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender {


currentNumber = currentNumber *10 + (float)[sender tag];
calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", currentNumber];
```

}

```
-(IBAction)buttonOperationPressed:(id)sender {
if (currentOperation ==0) result = currentNumber;
else {        

    switch (currentOperation) {
        case 1:
            result = result + currentNumber;
            break;
        case 2:
            result = result - currentNumber;
            break;
        case 3:
            result = result * currentNumber;
            break;
        case 4:
            result = result / currentNumber;
            break;
        case 5:
            currentOperation = 0;
            break;

    }
}

currentNumber = 0;
calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", result];
if ([sender tag] ==0) result=0;
currentOperation = [sender tag];
}



-(IBAction)cancelInput {

currentNumber =0;
calculatorScreen.text = @"0";

 }


-(IBAction)cancelOperation {



currentNumber = 0;
calculatorScreen.text = @"0";
currentOperation = 0;

}
```

Comment: This is the third question you've asked about this same topic.  Why have you accepted answers on those questions if you still don't understand how to deal with this issue?

Comment: It's the same question but I still haven't got an answer that works for me. I accept the answers to give the one who answered a few reputation points. I still can't get a good answer, so this time I am looking for a tutorial on a calculator. I don't know how to delete questions, and no one is answering my other ones about this, so I just asked again. I feel kind of bad asking it again, but then again, no one is answering the others.

Comment: @iOS developer - You are under no obligation to accept answers that don't solve your problem.  If you don't feel that the current answers address what you really want, please edit your original question to make your needs more clear.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Simple and direct.

Changed the currentNumber to store the current string value of the ongoing calculation (Make this `NSMutableString`), added an outlet (`buttonDecialPointPressed`) for the decimal point button.

```
-(IBAction) buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender
{
    currentNumber = [currentNumber appendFormat:@"%d"];
    calculatorScreen.text = currentNumber;
}

- (IBAction) buttonDecialPointPressed:(id)sender
{
    if(behindTheDecimal == YES)
        return;
    behindTheDecimal = YES;
    currentNumber = [currentNumber appendString:@"."];
    calculatorScreen.text = currentNumber;
}

-(IBAction)buttonOperationPressed:(id)sender
{
    float number = [currentNumber floatValue];
    switch (currentOperation)
    {
        case 0:
            result = number;
            break;
        case 1:
            result = result + number;
            break;
        case 2:
            result = result - number;
            break;
        case 3:
            result = result * number;
            break;
        case 4:
            result = result / number;
            break;
        case 5:
            currentOperation = 0;
            break;
        case 6:
            break;
    }

    currentNumber = [currentNumber stringWithFormat:@"%f", result];
    calculatorScreen.text = currentNumber;

    // why is this needed, how is it used?
    currentOperation = [sender tag];
}


-(IBAction)cancelInput
{
    behindTheDecimal = NO;
    currentNumber = @"0";
    calculatorScreen.text = currentNumber;  
}

-(IBAction)cancelOperation
{
    behindTheDecimal = NO;
    currentNumber = @"0";
    calculatorScreen.text = currentNumber;
    currentOperation = 0;
}
```

Comment: Except that this code allows for multiple decimal point entries. You need to check to see if there is a decimal point already and ignore it if there is.

Comment: True, fixed for the simple cases.